# Is there a blackboard bold letter for the set of Boolean numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Is there a symbol (e.g. $\mathbb{B}$) for the [special set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Special_sets) of Boolean numbers or values; ${0,1}$ or ${True,False}$?

Comment: If you want such a notation, use $\Bbb B$; just explain the notation at the start. The notations $\Bbb Z_2$ or $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ might be regarded as referring to a set with those same two elements, but they have sort of a different flavor, referring to a field (in the abstract-algebra sense), not a Boolean algebra.

Comment: While not boldface, the trivial Boolean Algebra is (at least in set theory) frequently denoted by the number $2$. (See for example Jensen's handwritten notes about subproper/subcomplete/... forcings.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Can't $\mathbb{F}_2$ be used for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to an answer by popular request:

If you want such a notation, use $\Bbb B$; just explain the notation at the start. The notations $\Bbb Z_2$ or $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ might be regarded as referring to a set with those same two elements, but they have sort of a different flavor, referring to a field (in the abstract-algebra sense), not a Boolean algebra.

Stefan reminds us that in set theory one writes $2=\{0,1\}$. That notation is I think much less common outside set theory.

Comment: On this site, `$\Bbb 2$` renders as $\Bbb 2$, whereas U+1D7DA renders as .